# Unable to call pure abstract base class overload

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overloading, abstract-class

Why does the following code not compile and what can I do about it? Shouldn't it find the pure abstract method declared in the base class?

```
#include <string>

using namespace std::string_literals;

struct A
{
    virtual void func1(int) = 0;
    virtual void func1(std::string) = 0;
};

struct B : A
{
    void func1(int) override
    {
        func1("bla"s);
    }
};

struct C : B
{
    void func1(std::string) override
    {
    }
};
```

`error C2664: 'void B::func1(int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'int'`

Thanks in advance,
Martin

**Edit about the linker error!**

If have three files:

file test.h

```
#include <string>

using namespace std::string_literals;

struct A
{
    virtual void func1(int) = 0;
    virtual void func1(std::string) = 0;
};

struct B : A
{
    void func1(int) override
    {
        A::func1("bla"s);
    }
};

struct C : B
{
    void func1(std::string) override;
};
```

file test.cpp

```
void C::func1(std::string)
{

}
```

file main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    C c;

    return 0;
}
```

This leads to

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ""public: virtual void __thiscall A::func1(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (?func1@A@@UAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)" in Funktion ""public: virtual void __thiscall B::func1(int)"

I'm using visual C++ v140.

It works with `using A::func1;`. What is the difference?

Comment: `A::func1("bla"s);` or `using A::func1;` inside of `B` definition so both overloads could be found by name lookup inside of `B`

Comment: B is missing `void func1(std::string) override = 0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B`'s implementation of `func1` hides the other two overloads from `A`. You can import them back into `B`'s interface by:

```
struct B
{
    using A::func1;
    /* ... */
};
```

In *general*, you can alternatively call a base class' overloads directly:

```
void /*B::*/func1(int) override
{
    A::func1("bla"s);
}
```

This will call *exactly* the version of the base class, though, *not* an overriding variant of, but in given case, `A`'s variant of is pure virtual (i. e. does not exist), and thus we cannot apply this approach here.

Comment: "using A::func1" is working. Declaring the abstract method in B again is working, too. But I get a linker error with A::func1("bla"s). Not for this small example. But in my real code. I assume It has to do with the fact that some functions are inline and others are not.

Comment: I've added some information about the linker error.

Comment: @MartinFehrs My fault: `A::func1` is pure virtual, so we cannot call it directly... Adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have the same problem with `C` - this will not compile:

```
C c;
c.func1(123);
```

Name lookup happens before overload resolution, and lookup stops in the scope where the first match is found.

You can introduce all the overloads into the scope of a derived class using `using`:

```
struct B : A
{
    using A::func1;  // Make the string overload available trough B's interface.
    void func1(int) override
    {
        func1("bla"s);
    }
};

struct C : B
{
    using B::func1; // Make the int overload available through C's interface.
    void func1(std::string) override
    {
    }
};
```

Your code would also compile if you called `A::func1(std::string)` *and* provided an implementation for it;

```
struct A
{
    virtual void func1(int) = 0;
    virtual void func1(std::string) = 0;
};

// Yes, you can provide an implementation for a pure virtual function.
void A::func1(std::string) {}

struct B : A
{
    void func1(int) override
    {
        A::func1("bla"s);
    }
};
```

but this code - which you probably want to work - would not:

```
void foo(B* b)
{
    b->func1("blargh"s);
}
```

Comment: I've added some information about the linker error.

Comment: @MartinFehrs I've done the same about how you can get rid of the linker error.